# Ran into an error with my PHP file, won't send email despite changes made to xampp files

Tags: php, email, xampp

As stated above, my PHP file won't send to the email requested. I get this error message: 'Warning: mail(): "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing in...' I have $from in there and I have changed the 'from' email in the php.ini file in xampp. This is driving me crazy can anybody help?

here is my code:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$request = $_POST['request'];

$from = "fromemil@email.com";
$to = "toemail@email.com";
$subject = "It's just a test";
$body = "This is just a test to see if things are working okay $request";

mail ($from,$to,$subject,$body); 

echo "Message sent!"
?>
```

Comment: the signature: `mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers)`; the headers are optional (you could set from)

Comment: changed the $from to $headers and I still get the same message

Comment: from php.net:
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>

Comment: great we are making progress, I get this error message now though "Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in"

Comment: you probably don't have an SMTP server installed on your local host; a tool to work from local environment smtp4dev.codeplex.com/, (otherwise run the code on your web host, servers are all set-up to run it.